# PIE styling with IE9 stopped working

Tags: html, css, gradient, css3pie

I had started a web page (for use with IE9, the local standard) using PIE styling for the gradient.  **The gradient worked, looked good**.  Started adding other features into the page, and the gradient disappeared.  Took out all the changes I made, and it still didn't work.

When the page loads, you can see the gradient flash before the background is set to all white.

It does work in Chrome.

I don't understand what changed if I backed out all the changes I made to when the gradient worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Training Registration Admin</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style type="text/css">
            hr{
                border-color: ivory; //Chrome and Safari
                background-color: ivory; //firefox and Opera
                color: ivory; //IE9
            }
            div, table{
                width: 100%;
            }
            html{
                height: 100%;
            }
            body{
                color: ivory;
                background: #000000;
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#000000), to(#48525C));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000, #48525C);
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(#000000, #48525C);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(#000000, #48525C);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(#000000, #48525C);
                background: linear-gradient(#000000, #48525C);
                -pie-background: linear-gradient(#000000, #48525C);
                behavior: url(stylesheets/PIE/PIE.htc);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 33%;text-align: center;">
                        <img src="images/traininglogo.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center;">
                        <h1>Department Training Scheduler</h1>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 33%;text-align: center;">
                        <img src="images/traininglogo.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used PIE.htc before to implement gradients in IE9, although I found SVG files to be a better way to do so.

Here you have an example of a SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myLinearGradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#000000" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#48525C" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient1);" />
</svg>
```

To use it in your code, only do this:

```
header {
  background-image: url("svg-gradient.svg");
}
```

Comment: I used your svg example, and still got the same thing.  Then I ran across a reference to the IE9 Compatibility Mode and forced it to IE9....and it worked.  Wasn't the PIE or SVG after all, it seems.  I'll keep the svg in because it's something I never played with before, tho.